# porqué mi sitio aparece como 404 y this site can't be reach?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

Hola buenas tardes comunidad.

Me pasaron unos accesos a cpanel para cargar un sitio de wordpress, cuando entro al file manager veo que está el folder public_html con un index.php del proveedor de hosting y varios folders dentro (otros sitios).

Creé un folder así public_html/inicio
Puse los archivos de wordpress ahí, la db igual la cargué de manera correcta, cambié las urls y todo.

El tema está que cuando escribo el dominio: ejemplo.com aveces aparece el index.php del proveedor del servicio y otras veces aparece como 404 no se pudo encontrar el sitio o no se puede acceder al sitio. Está demasiado raro, no he realizado ninguna configuración a nivel dns ni en apache.

Este cpanel no tiene accesso por ssh entonces no me puedo conectar a ver los .htaccess , también tiene muchos subdominios creados, e incluso un redireccionamiento a otro folder, ejemplo.com/folder pero el re direccionamiento no está explícito en Redirects.

No entiendo que puede estar causando este error, en la zona de dns no veo nada raro.
El proveedor de servicios es Neubox.

Alguien me podría ayudar o dar ideas de que podría ser?

En resumen: el dominio del sitio a veces se ve y a veces no, sin ninguna razón, es más el tiempo que no encuentra el sitio al tiempo que si lo encuentra.

Cosas que he intentado:

Limpiar cookies de mi web browser.

Acceder al sitio con https y con http, con www y sin www.

Gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 0):

OK. El error 404 es un código de estado que se envía desde el servidor web al navegador, o sea, al usuario que intentaba entrar en dicha página. Básicamente, lo que indica este error es que se trata de un enlace roto, defectuoso o que ya no existe y que, por lo tanto, no es posible navegar por él.

Verifica que la entrada DNS apunte a la misma que la IP del CPanel o que tu dominio tenga los NS (NameServers) apunten al DNS que tiene los registros.

Éxitos!